# How to keep a popup window open

Tags: node.js, typescript

We have a node js application where we open a popup window on button click with window.open(). The popup window opens and stays open in firefox. In edge browser the popup window opens and closes immediately. Is there a way to force the popup window stay open in any browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This behaviour sounds like it is browser-specific security closing the pop-up as it may be getting flagged as spam/scam in case your content may be interpreted in that way.

Comment: The popup is used for print functionality, no external site URL used. Is there a way to tell the browser the content is safe. Or is there a way to set timeout to force open the window?